# add and remove text field dynmaically in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to add and remove text fields in angularjs with an add button click. And in the right side of the text fields, which were added there should be a remove option. While I click on the remove the text field should delete.

Comment: The principle of angular is always the same: the point of truth is the model, and the view is generated from the model. So, have an array of objects in your model, and use ng-repeat to have one text field for each object in the array. To add a text field, add an object to the array. To remove a text field, remove the corresponding object from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-repeat to achieve this functionality.
You'll have to add an object in a $scope object's array everytime the user presses Add button and removing the object when the user presses - button.

Here's the code sample.

```
<span ng-click="addTextBox()"> + </span>
<div ng-repeat="textBox in textBoxes">
    <input type='text' />
    <span ng-click="removeTextBox(textBox.id)"> - </span>
</div>
```

The controller goes like this

```
$scope.textBoxes = [];
$scope.addTextBox = function() {
    $scope.textBoxes.push({id: $scope.textBoxes.length +1});
}
$scope.removeTextBox = function(id){
    var indexToRemove;
    for(i = 0; i < $scope.textBoxes.length; i++){
        if($scope.textBoxes[i].id === id){
            indexToRemove = i;
        }
        $scope.textBoxes.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why pass an id to removeTextBox()? Just pass the textBox itself, and use indexOf() to find its index in the array. Much simpler and more natural.

Comment: Or just pass the `$index`, then you already have the index to splice

Comment: @Pavan array.indexOf(object) will give you the index of the object inside the array

Comment: Yes, of course indexOf() works fine with objects. Passing $index is a bad idea: if you start using a filter to filter or sort the elements in the view, $index won't match the index in the model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is usefull

Comment: Angular arrays be special. It generally does not work on javascript arrays. How would it know which field/key to compare with in indexOf

Comment: indexOf() just uses ===. An object is only === to itself. There is no such thing as an angular array. Your code uses a regular, standard JavaScript array.

Answer (score 3):

I would solve this using **ng-repeat**. Have a look at this example:
**Edit** updated the code:

```js
angular.module("module",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.inputList = [];
  $scope.add = function(){
    $scope.inputList.push({content:""});
  };
  $scope.remove = function(input){
    var idx = $scope.inputList.indexOf(input);
    $scope.inputList.splice(idx,1)
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="module" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="input in inputList">
    <input type="text" ng-model="input.content">
    <input type="button" ng-click="remove(input)" value="remove">
  </div>
  <input type="button" ng-click="add()" value="add">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple way:

**HTML**

```
<span ng-repeat="hobby in hobbies track by $index">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type='text' ng-model='hobbies[$index]' class="form-control pull-right"/>
        <button ng-click = "addHobby()" ng-show="$last">+</button>
        <button ng-click = "removeHobby($index)" ng-show="hobbies.length > 1">-</button>
    </div>
</span>
```

**Angular Controller**

```
$scope.hobbies = [''];

$scope.addHobby = function() {
    $scope.hobbies.push('');
}

$scope.removeHobby = function(index) {
    if(index >= 0){
        $scope.hobbies.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```